# Laravel Vapor Blob responses are empty

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-vapor

On my local environment the following works, but not on the Vapor instance. Connection to S3 is working, so that's not the issue.

```
return Storage::disk('s3')->download($s3Path, 'export.xls', [
   'X-Vapor-Base64-Encode' => 'True',
]);
```

It should return a `Blob` response.

```
import FileDownload from "js-file-download";
function downloadFile() {
    axios({
        url: "/api/working-url",
        method: "GET",
        responseType: "blob",
    })
        .then((response) => {
            FileDownload(response.data, "export.xls");
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```

Locally it's working, so it's probably something I'm missing for the Vapor config.
When I download the file via Vapor, it's an empty file.